# How to export from Excel and import into R?

Tags: r, excel

What I want to do is calculate a function based on the group's list of cells.

I have a column filled of information, on which I would like to perform an integration function, a feature that does not exist in Microsoft Excel at this time.

My unique needs are for R to directly take this data, perform the operation (for which I have already figured out the process of coding) and then finally, get the program to move these outputs back to their corresponding locations.

How can this be done? Thank you.

P.S. It seems like some people have thought this question was too vague/unclear. I am performing many operations, functions, and calculations with my spreadsheet, and there fore I cannot export to a CSV or text file without losing my most valuable data. As a result, I consequently won't be able to afford giving up this information.

However, I can say that I have a bunch of numbers (quantitative measurements my team and I have made) that I need to run a function on, with "x" being the base and limits for a calculus-related integral problem. These relationships mean that I only want the result pasted onto the following portion of the detailed solution?

Because I have no other way to do so, the corresponding answer should then show up in the column beside the originally desired outcome. Subsequently, if any method exists to add this feature to the ideas allowed within Excel, please inform me in such is so. Thank you all, and I hope this has cleared this up for them!

Comment: `?readxl::read_excel` or `?read.csv`. The latter is more common and less troublesome.

Answer (score 4):

You can save your Excel spreadsheet (assuming it is a single sheet) as a CSV with headers. Use `df = read.csv(file path)` or `df = read.csv(file.choose())` (navigate to path) within R to import your data into a dataframe named df. Once you've performed your desired operations, you can write your results dataframe (eg `results_df`) to a CSV on your hard drive using `write.csv(results_df, save_path)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is copy the column with the necessary information and place it into a new excel sheet, and export that sheet as a csv file or a txt file (whatever format you want). These can then be used in R, and it will contain the info that you need.

Comment: @Anna If it is a matter of losing all the work, due to formulas and calculations, then just copy the data and "Paste As Values" into a new excel sheet or tab, and just continue on from there. This will retain all the numbers and keep the values that you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `readxl::read_excel()` for reading in files with `.xls` extension and `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` for files with `.xlsx` extension. Then, you can run your integration and use `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` to save to a new spreadsheet.

Comment: readxl package can read and write both .xls and .xlsx file types.

Comment: @Dave2e, Let me expound upon that a little. I personally use and recommend `openxlsx` package for _writing_ xlsx files because it offers finer granularity of control and has more options like embedding plots, etc.